# Django REST Framework:Serializerで取得結果を１つのリストにする

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django REST Frameworkでマスタからデータを取得するAPIを作成しています。
models.py

```
class CommonMaster(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type_id = models.IntegerField()
    key_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1024,null=True)
```

レコード：

```
{"id":"1", "type":"cat", "type_id":"1", "key_name":"Breed", "value":"Somali"}
{"id":"2", "type":"cat", "type_id":"1", "key_name":"Country", "value":"Canada"}
{"id":"3", "type":"cat", "type_id":"2", "key_name":"Breed", "value":"Bengal"}
{"id":"4", "type":"cat", "type_id":"2", "key_name":"Country", "value":"America"}
{"id":"5", "type":"dog", "type_id":"1", "key_name":"Breed", "value":"Shiba"}
{"id":"6", "type":"dog", "type_id":"1", "key_name":"Country", "value":"Japan"}
```

views.py

```
class CommonMasterViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serualizer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CommonMaster.objects.all()\
                           .filter(type=self.request.query_params['type'])\
                           .filter(key_name=self.request.query_params['type_id'])
```

serializer.py

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            obj.key_name : obj.value
        }
```

現在、取得結果は

```
[
    {
        "Breed": "Bengal"
    },
    {
        "Country": "America"
    }
]
```

のようになるのですが、以下のような形式でJSONを返したいと考えています。

```
[
    {
        "Breed": "Bengal",
        "Country": "America"
    },
]
```

Serializerの修正のみで実現可能でしょうか。
解決法がありましたらご教授いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: JSONとしては、同じ名前を複数持つオブジェクトも不正なものではないようですが、一般的な実装としては、同じ名前を複数は持てない辞書型などとするので、そのような形式では取扱い出来ない事が多いと思います。「{"key_name":"a", "value":["AAA","CCC"]}とかが理想的かもしれませんが、現状では不都合な受取側の事情を示してはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘を受け、データの例を修正しました。取得結果に同じ名前が連なることはなく、上のようになる想定です。説明文への配慮が足らずすみませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

`Serializer`の修正とかいろいろ考えていると難しくなるのですが、`Flask`でストレートに書くと簡単に書けます。

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine  = create_engine('接続文字列')

@app.route('/queryset')
def queryset():
    result = engine.execute('SELECT type, key_name FROM table_name')
    s = '[{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: f'"{x.type}":"{x.key_name}"', result)) + '}]'
    return Response(s, mimetype='application/json')
```

また、キーに重複がないのならば辞書が使えるのでもっと簡単です。

```
import json
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine  = create_engine('接続文字列')

@app.route('/queryset')
def queryset():
    result = engine.execute('SELECT type, key_name FROM table_name')
    return Response('[' + json.dumps(dict(list(result))) + ']', mimetype='application/json')
```

`Dgjango`でも難しく考えないで同じように書けばいいのではないでしょうか（`Dgjango`は使ったことがないのでよくわかりませんが、Viewsで`serializer`を使わないで`CommonMaster`から直接文字列を作成してそれを返すようにすればいいと思います）。